# Efficiently combine many IObservable<bool> streams with boolean operators

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm looking to combine many `IObservable<bool>` streams such that when the latest value for all of them is true, a true is emitted, and otherwise a false is emitted.

`CombinedLast` would allow me to build something like this for two streams easily, but a) I'm not sure the API easily allows thousands of streams to be combined and b) I'm not sure how efficient it would be even if it could.

`All` is kinda similar to what I want except I'm assuming that works over a single sequence and once false cannot dynamically changes back to true.

Also I need the values to be "distinct until changed", although the `DistintUntilChanged` operator may not be efficient for this?

I'm hoping for an O(1) algorithm.

Comment: By "all other times", do you mean that the result Observable should emit a value when any of the streams provides a value?

Comment: Is the number of streams constant? Or dynamic?

Comment: @shlomo yes the num of streams is constant

Comment: @supertopi i mean when any of the latest inputs turns false it emits a false, (but shouldnt emot false again until after next true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach for combining the latest is to start with a `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` and turn it in to a `IObservable<T[]>`. This becomes a very dynamic way to combine as many values you need.

Here's an extension method to do this:

```
public static IObservable<T[]> CombineLatest<T>(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> sources)
{
    return
        sources.Publish(ss =>
            Observable.Create<T[]>(o =>
            {
                var composite = new CompositeDisposable();
                var list = new List<T>();
                composite.Add(
                    ss.Subscribe(source =>
                    {
                        var index = list.Count;
                        list.Add(default(T));
                        composite.Add(source.Subscribe(x => list[index] = x));
                    }));
                composite.Add(ss.Merge().Select(x => list.ToArray()).Subscribe(o));
                return composite;
            }));
}
```

This nicely creates and tracks all subscriptions and uses a closure to define the `index` that each subscription needs to use to update its value in the `list` that is used for output.

If you use it like this:

```
var sources = new Subject<IObservable<bool>>();

var output = sources.CombineLatest();

output.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

var s1 = new Subject<bool>();
sources.OnNext(s1);
s1.OnNext(true);
var s2 = new Subject<bool>();
sources.OnNext(s2);
s2.OnNext(false);
var s3 = new Subject<bool>();
sources.OnNext(s3);
s3.OnNext(true);
s2.OnNext(true);
s1.OnNext(false);
```

Then you get this output:

[image: output]

If you change the definition of `output` to `var output = sources.CombineLatest().Select(xs => xs.Aggregate((x, y) => x & y));` then you get the output that I think you're after:

```
True
False
False
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it would work. But I have a intuition there is a clever functional approach to this that would not require you to constantly re-evaluate the boolean operator across your array on every OnNext. @schlomo is using mutable state tracking (counting), which should work but I feel like there must be a clever way to approach this, it maybe even one that would work across all different boolean operators. But maybe not ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Schneider - What do you mean by "constantly re-evaluate the boolean operator across your array on every OnNext"?

Comment: For each OnNext in any of the n child streams, you're calling .Aggregate, a O(n) operation.

Comment: @Shlomo - where `n` is the number of observables produced by the outer observable - which would be low in practical terms.

Comment: His question says O(1) because there's thousands of streams.

Comment: @Shlomo - It'd be a matter of him testing how well this works. It'd be interesting.

Comment: @shlomo, enigmativity I shall be testing out some of these solutions at work today. Will get back to you both :)

Comment: @Schneider - The `@` notifications only work for one user. If you want to sent two notifications you need to post two comments.

Comment: Yes just found that out the hard way :) Apologies for not giving you a full @Enigmativity ;-)

Comment: I ended up using this solution, although as it turns out (because the number of sequences is constant) I can use the built-in `CombineLatest` which accepts a `IEnumerable<IObservable<bool>>`. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in a classically functional way and still achieve O(1). This used mutable state, and is O(1) for observing each message, but O(n) for memory:

```
public IObservable<bool> CombineBooleans(this IObservable<bool>[] source)
{
    return source.Select((o, i) => o.Select(b => (value: b, index: i)))
        .Merge()
        .Scan((array: new bool[source.Length], countFalse: source.Length), (state, item) =>
        {
            var countFalse = state.countFalse;

            if (state.array[item.index] == item.value)
                return (state.array, countFalse);           //nothing to change, emit same state
            else if (state.array[item.index])               //previous/current state is true, becoming false
            {
                countFalse++;
                state.array[item.index] = false;
            }
            else                                            //previous/current state is false, becoming true
            {
                countFalse--;
                state.array[item.index] = true;
            }
            return (state.array, countFalse);
        })
        .Scan((countFalse: source.Length, oldCountFalse: source.Length), (state, item) => (countFalse: item.countFalse, oldCountFalse: state.countFalse))
        .SelectMany(state =>
            state.countFalse == 1 && state.oldCountFalse == 0
                ? Observable.Return(false)
                : state.countFalse == 0 && state.oldCountFalse == 1
                    ? Observable.Return(true)
                    : Observable.Empty<bool>()
        )
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();
}
```

**EDIT**: Added `.Publish().Refcount()` to eliminate multiple-subscriber bugs.

Comment: Watch out with the use of `.Publish().Refcount()` as it makes the observable only produce values once. It's not a great pattern to use all the time. What multiple subscriber bugs are you seeing?

Comment: My mistake; doesn't really matter here. I was thinking if you have double subscriber, then you get double mutation. But that has no effect on the state anyway.